# firemonkey and global hot key?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

I'm looking for a way to cach a global hotkey in firemonkey app (windows only, at least for now).
After some frustration and googling this is supposed to work:
register hotkey with winapi call

```
RegisterHotKey(FmxHandleToHWND(form1.Handle), 0 , MOD_CONTROL, $41);
```

it returns true.
and then catch the hotkey in a forms' procedure

```
procedure WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey); message WM_HOTKEY;
```

but this one is never called. 
I've used to do that in vcl apps before so my guess is that firemonkey handles messages in different way. 
So the question is: How do I catch global hotkeys in firemonkey app?

edit: some example of applying that solution. I've created an unit with little class

```
unit fire_hotkey;

interface

uses windows, messages,allocatehwnd;

type
  TMsgHandler = procedure (var Msg: TMessage) of object;

  THotClass = class(TObject)
    fMsgHandlerHWND : HWND;
    proc:TMsgHandler;
    constructor Create;
    procedure init;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ hotClass }

constructor THotClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;

end;

destructor THotClass.Destroy;
begin
  ThreadDeallocateHWnd(fMsgHandlerHWND);
  inherited;
end;

procedure THotClass.init;
begin
   fMsgHandlerHWND := ThreadAllocateHWnd(proc,true);
end;

end.
```

then my main form has a procedure for processing hotkey events:

```
procedure TformEditor.WMHotKey(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_HOTKEY then
  begin
    //call lua function or sth
    //...
  end
  else
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(hotkeyGrabber.fMsgHandlerHWND, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
end;
```

and there is a global hotkeyGrabber:THotClass; that gets initialized on form create:

```
  hotkeyGrabber:=THotClass.Create;
  hotkeyGrabber.proc:=WMHotKey;
  hotkeyGrabber.init;
```

after that you should register hotkeys like in usual vcl app and they will be cought
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=147
hope it makes sense

Comment: Someone pm'ed me on how to actually use that solution so I added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FMX framework won't route messages to your form. So, your `WMHotKey` will never be called because the FMX framework never calls `Dispatch`. You can see that this is the case by inspecting the `WndProc` method declared in the implementation section of the `FMX.Platform.Win` unit.

The easiest way to solve this problem will be to create your own window by calling `CreateWindow`. And then implementing a window procedure for that window that will handle the `WM_HOTKEY` message.

I've wrapped those low-level API calls like this:

```
unit AllocateHWnd;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.SyncObjs, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows;

function ThreadAllocateHWnd(AMethod: TWndMethod; MessageOnly: Boolean): HWND;
procedure ThreadDeallocateHWnd(Wnd: HWND);

implementation

const
  GWL_METHODCODE = SizeOf(Pointer)*0;
  GWL_METHODDATA = SizeOf(Pointer)*1;
  ThreadAllocateHWndClassName = 'MyCompanyName_ThreadAllocateHWnd';

var
  ThreadAllocateHWndLock: TCriticalSection;
  ThreadAllocateHWndClassRegistered: Boolean;

function ThreadAllocateHWndProc(Window: HWND; Message: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Proc: TMethod;
  Msg: TMessage;
begin
  Proc.Code := Pointer(GetWindowLongPtr(Window, GWL_METHODCODE));
  Proc.Data := Pointer(GetWindowLongPtr(Window, GWL_METHODDATA));
  if Assigned(TWndMethod(Proc)) then begin
    Msg.Msg := Message;
    Msg.wParam := wParam;
    Msg.lParam := lParam;
    Msg.Result := 0;
    TWndMethod(Proc)(Msg);
    Result := Msg.Result
  end else begin
    Result := DefWindowProc(Window, Message, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

function ThreadAllocateHWnd(AMethod: TWndMethod; MessageOnly: Boolean): HWND;

  procedure RegisterThreadAllocateHWndClass;
  var
    WndClass: TWndClass;
  begin
    if ThreadAllocateHWndClassRegistered then begin
      exit;
    end;
    ZeroMemory(@WndClass, SizeOf(WndClass));
    WndClass.lpszClassName := ThreadAllocateHWndClassName;
    WndClass.hInstance := HInstance;
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc := @ThreadAllocateHWndProc;
    WndClass.cbWndExtra := SizeOf(TMethod);
    Winapi.Windows.RegisterClass(WndClass);
    ThreadAllocateHWndClassRegistered := True;
  end;

begin
  ThreadAllocateHWndLock.Acquire;
  Try
    RegisterThreadAllocateHWndClass;
    if MessageOnly then begin
      Result := CreateWindow(ThreadAllocateHWndClassName, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, HInstance, nil);
    end else begin
      Result := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, ThreadAllocateHWndClassName, '', WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, nil);
    end;
    Win32Check(Result<>0);
    SetWindowLongPtr(Result, GWL_METHODDATA, NativeInt(TMethod(AMethod).Data));
    SetWindowLongPtr(Result, GWL_METHODCODE, NativeInt(TMethod(AMethod).Code));
  Finally
    ThreadAllocateHWndLock.Release;
  End;
end;

procedure ThreadDeallocateHWnd(Wnd: HWND);
begin
  Win32Check(DestroyWindow(Wnd));
end;

initialization
  ThreadAllocateHWndLock := TCriticalSection.Create;

finalization
  ThreadAllocateHWndLock.Free;

end.
```

This is a thread-safe version of the VCL `AllocateHWnd` which is notorious for being unusable outside the main thread.

What you need to do is create a class with a window procedure, i.e. something that implements a `TWndMethod`. It can be an instance method or a class method. Then simply call `ThreadAllocateHWnd` to create the window, and pass that window to `RegisterHotKey`. When it's time to unwind it all, unregister your hot key, and destroy the window with a call to `ThreadDeallocateHWnd`.